# Applying text-overflow:ellipses properly

Tags: css

I've been trying to get this CSS applied to certain sections, but despite reading up on the style, and remembering to include overflow:hidden along with the text-overflow, I can't get it to work. Below is some code without the text-overflow style. Where do I need to apply it? I thought it was just on the div that contains the text.

```
<main>
    <div class="indexr1">
        <section class="indexc1b">
            <h1>header</h1>
            <div class="bl">
                <div class="prev">Placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholderPlaceholder placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholderPlaceholder placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholderPlaceholder placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholder</div>
            </div>
            <div class="blM">
                <div class="prev">Placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholderPlaceholder placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholderPlaceholder placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholderPlaceholder placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholder Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff last</div>
            </div>
            <div class="bl">
                <div class="prev">Placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholderPlaceholder placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholderPlaceholder placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholderPlaceholder placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholderPlaceholder placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholderPlaceholder placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholderPlaceholder placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholderPlaceholder placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholderPlaceholder placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholderPlaceholder placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholderPlaceholder placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholderPlaceholder placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholder.</div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'Roboto';
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:400;
    src:url(/resources/font.woff) format('woff');
}
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:small;
    font-family:Roboto;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-decoration:none;
}
main {
    font-size:0;
    line-height:1.5;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:86%;
    min-width:1000px;
}
section {
    border:1px solid #BBB;
    background:#FFF;
    border-radius:7px;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
h1 {
    background:linear-gradient(#444, #000, #444);
    padding:5px;
    color:#FFF;
}
.indexr1 {
    display:inline-block;
    width:66%;
    height:710px;
    margin-right:5px;
    font-size:0;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.indexc1b {
    width:100%;
    font-size:0;
    height:355px;
}
.bl {
    vertical-align:top;
    width:33%;
    display:inline-block;
}
.blM {
    vertical-align:top;
    width:33%;
    display:inline-block;
    border-left:1px solid #BBB;
    border-right:1px solid #BBB;
}
.prev {
    text-align:justify;
}
```

EDIT: [Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xp9kV/)

Answer (score 0):

Set a text-overflow, overflow and white-space.

```
.prev {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;     
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xp9kV/1/

Note: this will work only on a single line text.

Comment: But that just trades one problem for another. All that space and only one line available for use is just pointless.

Comment: I don't think you can fix this issue with css only